# Doctrine DBAL parameters not working

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm, silex

Hi I'm using PHP Silex with Doctrine DBAL query builder (no ORM) and SQLite. It sort of works, so I can build a query and it spits back results, but I for the life of me I can't get setting parameters to work (I get empty array all the time).

Here's what works:

```
$qb->select('*')
            ->from('photos')
            ->where("country = '".$country."'")
            ->andWhere('status = 1')
            ->orderBy($sort[0], $sort[1])
            ->setFirstResult($start)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
```

For obvious reasons I would like to replace that with:

```
$qb->select('*')
            ->from('photos')
            ->where("country = ?") /// <--
            ->andWhere('status = 1')
            ->orderBy($sort[0], $sort[1])
            ->setFirstResult($start)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setParameter(0, $country) /// <--
```

Or:

```
$qb->select('*')
            ->from('photos')
            ->where("country = :country") /// <--
            ->andWhere('status = 1')
            ->orderBy($sort[0], $sort[1])
            ->setFirstResult($start)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setParameter(':country', $country) /// <--
```

Or even:

```
$qb = $this->db->createQueryBuilder(); 
$expr = $qb->expr();
$qb->select('*')
            ->from('photos')
            ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq('country', '?1'), /// <--
                $qb->expr()->eq('status', 1)
            ))
            ->orderBy($sort[0], $sort[1])
            ->setFirstResult($start)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setParameter(1, $country) /// <--
```

These are all examples of setting params I found in the docs, however none of them seems to work and I'm not sure how to debug that. Checking $qb->getSQL() and $qb->getParams() doesn't seem to show anything useful.

Im using `("doctrine/dbal": "~2.2")` if that matters.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't seem to work", no results returned?

Comment: Exactly. No error. Just empty results array. The first way returns rows as expected. Just what's shown changes.

Comment: Have you tried `->setParameter('country', $country)` (without the colon)

Comment: No. How should I declare the param in where() method then? With or without the colon?

Comment: `->where("country = :country")` and `->setParameter('country', $country)`.

Comment: Sadly, same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115192/discussion-between-mickadoo-and-konrad).

Comment: Did you check the resulting sql statement? That might give you a hint.

Comment: From what I know you can't actually see the final produced SQL cause the way it works your prepared SQL and the actual params are sent separately to the DB (you can access them with `$qb->getSQL()` and `$qb->getParams()`). So there's no string with the resulting query to see.

Comment: This should work:
    $qb->select('*')
            ->from('photos')
            ->where("country = :country") /// <-- here you need the ":"
            ->andWhere('status = 1')
            ->orderBy($sort[0], $sort[1])
            ->setFirstResult($start)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setParameter('country', $country) /// <-- no ":" here

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well. This may be something with db config, so I'll test that as well. I got one interesting suggestion in chat. We'll se how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came back to my own question by accident cause I solved it long time ago and of course it turned out to be a silly thing. The problem lied not in building the query properly but using it the right way. Here's the answer for future reference.

With Query Builder you don't do:

```
$this->db->fetchAll($qb->getSQL()); 
// you get query with unfilled placeholders
```

but rather:

```
$qb->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Thanks to all who tried to help!

Comment: Please mark your own question as correct. It just shined a light on my gloomy Sunday afternoon development.